# Python is converting charcters to symbols

Tags: python, xml, sqlite, character-encoding

I have the trouble and dont know how to start solve it.

I have the XML-file. There is example:

```
<resources>
    <string name="menuOptionMdReceiptIcon">&#xf1b4;</string>
    <string name="menuOptionMdStoreMallDirectoryIcon">&#xf1d4;</string>
    <string name="menuOptionMdPersonIcon">&#xf207;</string>
    <string name="menuOptionMdLocalAtmIcon">&#xf198;</string>
    <string name="menuOptionMdSwapHorizIcon">&#xf30d;</string>
    <string name="menuOptionMdPeopleIcon">&#xf20d;</string>
</resources>
```

it is my code:

```
import sqlite3
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml


dict_4_3 = {}

db = sqlite3.connect("table.db")
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.executescript("""
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS V_4_3;
 CREATE TABLE V_4_3 (ID integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
 TAG_NAME_4_3 TEXT,
 VALUE_4_3 TEXT);
 """)

xmldoc = minidom.parse('strings_4_3.xml')
xmldoc.normalize()
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('string')


for s in itemlist:
    try:
        dict_4_3[s.attributes['name'].value] = s.childNodes[0].nodeValue
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO V_4_3 (TAG_NAME_4_3, VALUE_4_3) VALUES (?, ?)""", (s.attributes['name'].value,
                                                                                         s.childNodes[0].nodeValue))
    except:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO V_4_3 (TAG_NAME_4_3, VALUE_4_3) VALUES (?, ?)""", (s.attributes['name'].value,
                                                                                         None))
```

I just getting values from XML-file and want to put to SQLite DB. So my trouble is converting sequence like "&#xf20d" to  in the DB lines. How to force Python take values without changes and incert them to DB lines?

Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how XML works. The entity `&#xf20d;` indicates the character ``. Parsing the XML includes converting entities to the characters they indicate. Trying to retain the entity codes is probably a bad idea. SQLite should be able to store these characters.

However, if you really do need the entities, you can have Python convert non-ASCII characters back to entities before writing them to the database, e.g.

```
nodevalue = s.childNodes[0].nodeValue
nodevalue = nodevalue.encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace").decode()
# proceed to write nodevalue to database
```